# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( (\sum^n_{m=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}) - \sqrt{n} \right)$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( (\sum^n_{m=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}) - \sqrt{n} \right)$ : convergent?

**My attempt**

$$
(\sum^n_{m=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}) - \sqrt{n} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) + \cdots + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})
$$

But I stuck here.

Comment: Currently one answer says diverges, one says converges, one is just formulae and says neither!

Comment: I would imagine that the sum is like the integral of $x^{-1/2}$. This gives $2\sqrt{x}$. But the other bit is just like $\sqrt{x}$. So my guess is that the sequence is of order $\sqrt{n}$ still, which is in line with Severin Schraven's hint.

Comment: @T_M you are correct in your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
Note that for $1\leq j \leq \frac{n}{2}$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
Use this to find a lower bound of your sequence which divergeces.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is not convergent.  You can use the integral test to see this.

\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1} ^n  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} & \geq \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx \\ & = 2\sqrt{n} - 2 .
\end{align}
So we can conclude that
$$\sum_{m=1} ^n  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} - \sqrt{n} \ \geq \sqrt{n}- 2.$$

Letting $n \to \infty$ givs us what we want.

Comment: The answer has been edited.